# How to add custom Logs to android CTS?

Tags: android, cts

I am working with android Compatibility Test Suite (CTS).

I would want to add Logs in a few specific test modules and see the logs while running these tests in the CTS tradefed.

I tried adding android.util.Log and using Log.e but it didn't work.

Can anyone help me out with this on how can I add custom logs to CTS tests which show up on the tradefed console.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It actually works. For Java Code,We can use android.util.Log library and Log.x functions. For cpp code we can use cutils/log.h header file and use ALOGX functions. For kernel we can use printk function